# Limiting number of parallel jobs in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I would like to limit the job to parallel - 10 . My total job is around 150. How can I define "strategy: parallel" in my below yaml structure.
I have for each loop which creates more than 100 job. So taking more than 1 hrs to finish and also uses all agent. So want to limit the agent.
Can someone help?

Code below:

```
stages:
- stage: xxx
  jobs:
      - ${{ each v in parameters.vvv }}:
        - template: Templates/aa.yml
          parameters:
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a job with a `parallel` or `matrix` strategy, as explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#job). You can set the maximum degree of parallelism.

```
jobs:
- job: string  # name of the job (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore)
  strategy:
    parallel: # parallel strategy; see the following "Parallel" topic
    matrix: # matrix strategy; see the following "Matrix" topic
    maxParallel: number # maximum number of matrix jobs to run simultaneously
```

Comment: Thanks! But here For each loop is creating Job. I dont have any step called "job". When I am using strategy after "jobs", it is showing error. How can I use "strategy"  here?

Comment: @Snigdha Look at the documentation for the `matrix` strategy. You'll need to rework things a bit and remove your explicit loop, instead letting the matrix strategy perform the looping. The templated job would use the matrix strategy, at which point it probably wouldn't need to be a template anymore.